# Bitcoin Script tutorial

Tags: development, script

Are there any tutorials with examples on [Bitcoin Script](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script): from basics to complex scripts?

Answer (score 3):

Got these informative resources:

- https://blockgeeks.com/guides/best-bitcoin-script-guide/
- https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#p2pkh-script-validation
- https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/book.asciidoc
- https://davidederosa.com/basic-blockchain-programming/
- https://programmingblockchain.gitbooks.io/programmingblockchain/content/
- http://www.righto.com/2014/02/bitcoins-hard-way-using-raw-bitcoin.html
- http://www.samlewis.me/2017/06/a-peek-under-bitcoins-hood/
- https://blog.bitjson.com/bitauth-ide-write-and-debug-custom-bitcoin-scripts-aad51f6e3f44

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bitcoin script 101 tutorial

https://bitcoindev.network/bitcoin-script-101/

Comment: Link only answers are generally poor because the links die overtime, would you consider adding yours to the list that already is ongoing so only one set of links needs to be maintained?

Comment: Happy for it to be added